# Mongoose: boolean 'or' query with wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I' m trying to emuluate with Mongoose a fulltext search into two fields. I' ve spent most of the day testing several query types but I' ve always failed. The **MongoDB shell query** is this one:

```
db.feeds.item.find({lang:"en", $or:[{title: /searchexpression/}, {body: /searchexpression/}] })
```

In this example I want to return only english documents that matches the search expression (including a regex) in **title** or **body** fields or in both fields. This query works, but the problem starts, as I said, when trying to adapt it with **Mongoose**, :-(

Some expressions that I used and that didn' t work:

```
exports.fullTextSearch = function(lang, text, callback) { 
    MyModel.find({lang:lang, $or: [{title:/text/},{body:/text/}]}).exec(callback);
    MyModel.find({lang:lang, $or: [{title: new RegExp('\/'+text+'\/')}, {body:new RegExp('\/'+text+'\/')}]}).exec(callback);
    MyModel.find({lang:lang}).or({title:/text/},{body:/text/}).exec(callback);
    MyModel.find({lang:lang}).or({title:new RegExp('\/'+text+'\/')},{body:new RegExp('\/'+text+'\/')}).exec(callback);
```

}

Thank you very much!

Luis Cappa.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but according to the documentation this should work:

```
MyModel.find({lang:lang}).or([{title:/text/},{body:/text/}]).exec(callback);
```

Like your third example, but with the "or" conditions in an array.

EDIT:

To have the regex dynamic, use the fourth example, but with the "or" conditions in an array:

```
MyModel.find({lang:lang}).or([{title:new RegExp(text)},{body:new RegExp(text)}]).exec(callback);
```

Or define the regex outside :

```
var regexText = new RegExp(text)
MyModel.find({lang:lang}).or([{title:regexText},{body:regexText}]).exec(callback);
```

Comment: I' ve tried previosly the same query and didn´t work. I again copy-pasted exactly what you suggested and nothing, :-( I' m starting to think that maybe this is a Mongoose bug...

Comment: I simplified the query to execute the search into just one field like: MyModel.find({lang:lang, title: new RegExp('\/'+text+'\/')}).exec(callback); It could be a Mongoose bug related with regular expressions or even a non documented query component.

Comment: No bug! The problem is linked to the search expression itself. The search expression that executes the search comes from a HTTP request parameter, so maybe some decoding or special characters escaping issues are related with having no results. However, it' s strange, because when printing the search expression looks OK. I' ll continue testing.

Thank you a lot for your time, Ragnar!

Comment: Ok, html encoding can cause problems.